# How to use BroadcasetIntent() function in Monkeyrunner

Tags: monkeyrunner

Can anyone let me know how to use device.broadcastIntent function for the create contact using python script

Answer (score 0):

```
device.broadcastIntent('android.intent.action.INSERT',
'vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact', {'name':'user1501488', 'phone':'123-15489'})
```

For shell command try this

```
device.shell("am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT 
-t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'user1501488' -e phone 123-15489")
```